# onCreate called despite using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-lifecycle

I have 2 activities (A and B) and they have 2 buttons to switch between.

1. A oncreate
2. B oncreate
3. ***A oncreate***
4. A onresume

what I wanted to do is after sending intent from B to A oncreate should not be called but at this point it does. To overcome that I found FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT ([from here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb9d6nEbxrw)) and thought it could called only onresume but it didn't.

Comment: Why don't you just send a boolean inside a bundle to the other activity . If it's false, don't run the code inside the onCreate(). Edit: o nvm I guess you want the existing object.

Comment: If you activity is ever paused, there is a chance `onCreate()` will be called by system.

Comment: There are a lot of alternatives indeed but what I want to learn the logic. I mean what is for flag_activity_reorder_to_front?

Comment: The flag is exactly for this purpose. If you have 2 active activities (ie: not finished) and you want to switch between them, then you should use this flag. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` does exactly what you think it should do. However, if you start `ActivityA` and then `ActivityA` starts `ActivityB` and calls `finish()` on itself, then when `ActivityB` starts `ActivityA` with an Intent that has `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` there will be no instance of `ActivityA` to bring to the front. In this case Android will simply create a new one. I can only assume that is what you are seeing.

Comment: thank you David but finish() never be called. I just press back button to go to ActivityA. The thing that I can not understand is it works just what I want to do if I leave activity through the home button. So I wonder what are the differences between back and home button? Could you explain it if you have some time? And the other question is onSaveInstanceState raises while pressing home button, why does it work as I press back button?

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. If you leave activity via HOME button and then come back, it should show you exactly the same activity. For instance, if you have ActivityA on screen and press HOME button and then start application again, you should see ActivityA. Please post your manifest, maybe the problem is in there.

Comment: BACK button is used to finish the activity and return to the previous activity in the task's activity stack. HOME button just pushes the entire task stack into the background (it does NOT finish the current activity).

Comment: You should also post the code you use to switch from one activity to another.

Comment: thank you this is the answer that I need to know: BACK button is used to finish the activity and return to the previous activity in the task's activity stack. HOME button just pushes the entire task stack into the background (it does NOT finish the current activity).

Answer (score 0):

[`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) changes activity history. If the requested activity is found in the history of previously visited activities (in a task), the older history record  for this activity is cleared. So, while pressing back button, user will not encounter this activity in a task.

This flag won't affect the call to `onCreate()`, If activity does not exists in the task (not loaded or destroyed), `onCreate()` will be called to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just cancel onCreate. If B is full screen activity android can kill A activity and will recreate it when you try to restart it with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag and call it's onCreate method. If Activity A will be still alive at the monent when you try to bring it to front, onCreate method should not be called.

Maybe in your case you should try to use fragments?