# Android: sending data from one app to another NOT trough startActivity()

Tags: android

I need send a *message* from one app to another while both apps are in execution in foreground (I'm using multiview).
This will be a simple one-way only communication the message allows me to change the behaviour of the second application (the one receiving), I just need to communicate a pretty simple boolean/int value.
Up to now I'm doing so trough `Intent` and `startActivity()` method but this will trigger an `onCreate()` event on the receiving app that leads to an unwanted behaviour.

```
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("it.tux.gcs");
    intent.putExtra("BACKWARD_FLAG",camera.backward);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(intent);
```

There's a way to accomplish that?
I looked in **Android** docs but I've been able only to find a lot of `startActivity()` base examples.

Comment: Your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433120/how-to-use-putextra-to-open-another-app-and-send-some-data-for-it

Comment: nope. they are just suggesting to use `startActivity()`

Comment: ok use Broadcasts , here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492790/how-to-send-broadcast-from-one-app-to-another-app

Comment: I think an intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT may work here for you as well.

Comment: @DeanK this option will trigger onCreate() event ?

Comment: I don't think it should. Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224127/oncreate-called-despite-using-flag-activity-reorder-to-front, especially David Wasser's answer.

Comment: uhm... it looks like it does.